# MYSQL store procedure replace multiple results into one parameter: Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, replace, procedure

I have to write a store procedure MYSQL to get data from tables to send a notification for all customers about exchange rate every day with a notification template.

1. CUSTOMER

```
customerCode | name | nationCode
0000001      | A    | VNM
0000002      | B    | CNH
```

2. SYSTEM_NATION

```
id | nationCode | ccy
1  | VNM         | VND
2  | CNH         | CNY
```

3. EXCHANGE_RATE

```
id | ccyFrom | ccyTo | rate 
1 |  JPY     | VND  | 0.1
2 |  JPY     | CNY  | 0.3
```

4.NOTIFICATION_TOKEN

```
id | customerCode | tokenId 
1  | 0000001      | tokenExample1
2  | 0000002      | tokenExample2
```

Now I want to get the data to send a daily rate notification for each customer corresponding to `nationCode` of them with a text form like this:

```
  Exchange rate: 1 JPY = {noti}exchangeRate{noti} {noti}varNotiCCYTo{noti}.
```

And I expected

Customer 0000001

```
Exchange rate: 1 JPY = 0.1 VND.
```

Customer 0000002

```
Exchange rate: 1 JPY = 0.3 CNY.
```

I have store procedure to get data from tables I have mentioned above

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `gojp`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `NotiGetExchangeRateEveryDay`()

DECLARE     varNotiBODY nVarchar (9000);
DECLARE     varNotiCCYTo nvarchar(3);
DECLARE     varNotiExchangeRate Numeric (30,2);

###########################
#IMPORTANT: when I call this procedure, it responses 

    #Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row

#I think problem in this query: 

*select ex.ccyTo, ex.rate into varNotiCCYTo, varNotiExchangeRate from CUSTOMER cus
inner join SYSTEM_NATION sys on cus.nationCode= sys.nationCode 
inner join EXCHANGE_RATE ex on ex.ccyTo = sys.ccy;*
##########################

set varNotiBODY = (SELECT REPLACE(varNotiBODY, '{noti}exchangeRate{noti}', ifnull(varNotiExchangeRate,'')) from dual);
set varNotiBODY = (SELECT REPLACE(varNotiBODY, '{noti}varNotiCCYTo{noti}', ifnull(varNotiCCYTo,'')) from dual);


After that I want to insert all this table to get list of notification was sent.
INSERT INTO `gojp`.`NOTIFICATION_QUEUE` 
(`customerCode`,
`deviceID`,
`ntfBody`,
`createdDate`
) 
select 
noti.customerCode, 
noti.tokenId, 
varNotiBODY, 
now()
from NOTIFICATION_TOKEN noti 
inner join CUSTOMER cus on noti.customerCode = cus.customerCode;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to get data about exchange rate of each customer then replace into `{noti}exchangeRate{noti}`. However, it returns multiple results so I cannot insert into only one param.

So, anyone can give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do it with single insert:

```
INSERT INTO `gojp`.`NOTIFICATION_QUEUE` 
(`customerCode`,
`deviceID`,
`ntfBody`,
`createdDate`
) 
select 
  noti.customerCode, 
  concat('Exchange rate: 1 JPY = ',ex.ccyTo,' ', ex.rate,' ', sys.ccy,'.'),
  now()
from NOTIFICATION_TOKEN noti 
  join CUSTOMER cus on noti.customerCode = cus.customerCode
  join SYSTEM_NATION sys on cus.nationCode= sys.nationCode 
  join EXCHANGE_RATE ex on ex.ccyTo = sys.ccy
```

Comment: Great!!! I did it. I wonder why I didn't think simply ^^. Anyway, thank you so much.